# Troubles using npm with ASP.NET to import js modules

Tags: asp.net, node.js, npm, es6-modules, openlayers-6

**Background:**
I am running OpenLayers 6 on a Microsoft ASP.NET project in Visual Studio. I am following the OpenLayers 6 Map Export example to export my map to a png using the html-to-image js library. In the example the library is installed and managed by Node's package manager (npm) and the functions are accessed using Javascript import statements. Because I am not working in Node, I had to get npm working in my ASP.NET project so I installed Mads Kristensen's Web Extension Pack, Node and npm. Using npm, I downloaded and installed the html-to-image library which created a nodes_modules folder and placed the library inside. The library contains a number of typescript and js files (as shown below).

[image]

**Problem:**
I can't seem to access the library's functions using javascript import statements the way the OpenLayers examples show. Their example shows that you import the toPng function from the module the following way:

```
import {toPng} from 'html-to-image';
```

When I try to import the module that way, I get a failed to load resource 404 error. Next, I tried to import using relative paths:  `import { toPng } from '../../node_modules/html-to-image';` and I got a failed to load resource 403 (forbidden) error. I was, however, able to access the invididual js file where the toPng function resided `import { toPng } from '../../lib/utils.js';` but I got an error saying the requested module does not provide an export named 'toPng'. I'm pretty sure the js files from the library are not meant to be accessed individually this way.

**My main question is this**: How can I import the whole html-to-image module the way the Openlayers examples show? On my .NET project, it doesn't seem like you can use the import statements by referencing the module folder the way you can on Node. All the ES6 js module import examples I can find reference importing from a single .js file so I'm wondering how you access a module with multiple js files.

Is it possible this library was specifically written to be accessed using Node projects only? Is there a difference in the way you access ES6 js modules between a Node.js and a .NET project?

Any insights into this would be much appreciated!

Comment: You may also encounter browser compatibility issues with html-to-image.  The example is about to be updated, see https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/10541

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point to consider. I had also noticed that OL6 changed how the canvas works so that will be another issue to figure out.